# What kind of government abuse is "sell game"?

Tags: crime, africa, sierra-leone

I tried searching google but can't find anything that isn't related to gaming. Actually, is this even the right forum?

Anyway, the mention is from here.

"As for the government soldiers, Amy Smythe spelt out the links between their abuses (including ‘*sell game*’) and their experience of neglect at the hands of the government in Freetown:

A soldier 200 miles into the bush is being told to fight the rebels who are his brothers. He cannot eat. Why should he not compromise? What does the government mean for him – without weapons, food, money?"

Comment: *" the mention is from here."* I'm confused. Where is "here." Where does the quote originate?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because roosters don't lay eggs. (This is off-topic AND unclear)

Answer (score 3):

It's an allusion to "selling" a sports match ([in the sense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Match_fixing) of accepting money not to play to one's best), more precisely the [accusations were](http://www.lse.ac.uk/international-development/Assets/Documents/PDFs/csrc-working-papers-phase-one/wp14-since-I-am-a-dog-beware-my-fangs.pdf) that (some) soldiers were playing both sides or effectively working for the enemy by doing the same things as the rebels or even cooperating with them in more-or-less staged fighting, e.g. by minimizing clashes:

> In a bizarre and terrifying process labelled by some Sierra Leoneans as ‘sell-game’ (a term
>   for a football match that has been fixed in advance), government soldiers in the early and
>   mid-1990s were observed not only looting and engaging in illegal diamond mining but also
>   killing civilians, engaging in illegal diamond mining, dressing up as rebels, selling arms to
>   rebels, and co-ordinating movements with rebels so as to minimise clashes and maximise the
>   exploitation of civilians.

See also ["Phoney War"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phoney_War) which may be analogous to some extent (at least as an accusation).